# Props empty in child until I refresh parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a working app and no problems with props except when I have to filter those variables before sending them to a child component. Here's my parent component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import ItemDetail from './ItemDetail';

const ItemDetailContainer = () => {
    const { itemId } = useParams();
    const [catData, setCatData] = useState([]);
    const [prodData, setProdData] = useState([]);

    const getData = () => {
        fetch('/data.json', {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json',
            },
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (myJson) {
                setProdData(myJson['products'].find((c) => c.id == itemId));
                setCatData(myJson['categories'].find((c) => c.catId == prodData.catId));
            });
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    if (prodData === null || catData === null || prodData === undefined || catData === undefined) {
        return null;
    }

    return <ItemDetail prodInfo={prodData} catInfo={catData} />;
};

export default ItemDetailContainer;
```

When I receive those props in ItemDetail I get a blank object:

[image: Props as soon the page loads]

But when I go back to my code and hit save on ItemDetailContainer (parent component), I get the content from the childs' props:

[image: Props after I save the parent component]

I've tried using useEffect with and without dependencies, timeouts, intervals, returning from a function. I don't really know what else to try. Any clues?

BTW, I'm only displaying one of the props onto the console. That's why they are the same (I don't know why they always appear twice though).

Altough this question appears as duplicate, the other posts/answers don't make calculations with the recently acquired data which was my problem as stated.

Comment: you'll see the issue if you `console.log(prodData.catId)` right before `setCatData(myJson['categories'].find((c) => c.catId == prodData.catId));`

Comment: you cannot use `prodData` right after `setProdData(...)`.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstood life cycle. The state values defined by setCatData or setProddata can't change immediately. U should use useEffect hook whenever the state values changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be good for this matter.

```
 .then(function (myJson) {
    const tmp_prodData = myJson['products'].find((c) => c.id == itemId)
    setProdData(tmp_prodData);
    setCatData(myJson['categories'].find((c) => c.catId == tmp_prodData.catId));
 });

...

useEffect(() => {
   ...
}, [prodData, catData])
```

Comment: Why would OP need an effect hook watching the two state variables?

Comment: Thanks for this. I spent two days tryinf to figure this out and the one this I didn't try exactly like this was to create a direct assignment before using the variable. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

`useState` saves your values to the next render, so when you call `find(c.catId === prodData.catId)`, your `prodData.catId` is still the old one (since React hasn't re-render yet).

The solution is pretty straightforward, just don't use that state value and use what you've got from your json instead, somewhat like:

```js
    .then(function (myJson) {
      const newProductData = myJson['products'].find((c) => c.id == itemId
      setProdData(newProductData);
      setCatData(myJson['categories'].find((c) => c.catId == newProductData.catId));
    });
```

Another fyi: your logs appear twice because of React's Strict Mode. It will run your hooks twice in development environment to make sure everything is working as expected (and show warnings if it's not). You can turn that off but it's not recommended.